# How to tell if my phone is SIM Locked

Tags: lumia, sim

I want to sell a Lumia 925 and need to know if it is SIM Locked. Is it possible to find out if it is without using a SIM card from another provider (which I don't have)?

Comment: I have new info for you in my edit. Should clarify any doubt.

Answer (score 5):

Good question.

I don't know if this can help but at least in Lumia phones in extra+info there is a *"Manufacturer Name"* and *"Mobile Operator"*.

I think one of them can have information about the carrier and maybe it will tell you if it is associate with the carrier.

In my unlocked Lumia 920 I have this info:

[image]

You can see *RM-821-lta-brazil_253* that maybe can have carrier info in your case.

I believe the mobile operator give your more clue about this, in my case it says only *000-BR*. I think in case of carrier lock this 000 would changed to carrier number.

All this info is speculative. Here in Brazil is illegal lock the user to a carrier so they are not locking phones anymore (as far as I know) just making you sign the x years contract.

**Edit**

I found new information with help of [Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/know-your-country-variant-lumia-os-updates).

Basically it points to a official Windows Phone Dev article titled [Registry values for carrier-unlocked phones](https://dev.windowsphone.com/en-US/OEM/docs/Customization/Registry_values_for_carrier-unlocked_phones)

There you can see that, in my case, **000-BR** is a unlocked version for Brazil.

You just need to go to extra-settings and see which is your *Mobile Operator* and found in the list.

Comment: And mine says "ORG-UK" For an EE (was "Orange") locked phone.

Comment: Mine says "000-DE" for an unlocked German one. So having the three leading zeros seems to mean unlocked.

Comment: mine 000-GB payg phone from carphone warehouse uk looks unlocked

Comment: VOB-GB for me being locked to Virgin mobile